# Annotation with Transactional of CrudRepository's methods

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin

```
interface EntityRepository : CrudRepository<Entity, String> {

    @Transactional
    fun deleteById(id: String)
}
```

Hello,

what is the point of annotation of single `SQL statement` here? After all, AFAIK, single statements are transactions in from `RDBMS` point of view. Therefore, what is the purpose to annotate that?

Answer (score 0):

The base repository is annotated with `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`

From the docs:

> You can use transactions for read-only queries and mark them as such
>   by setting the readOnly flag. Doing so does not, however, act as a
>   check that you do not trigger a manipulating query (although some
>   databases reject INSERT and UPDATE statements inside a read-only
>   transaction). The readOnly flag is instead propagated as a hint to the
>   underlying JDBC driver for performance optimizations. Furthermore,
>   Spring performs some optimizations on the underlying JPA provider. For
>   example, when used with Hibernate, the flush mode is set to NEVER when
>   you configure a transaction as readOnly, which causes Hibernate to
>   skip dirty checks (a noticeable improvement on large object trees).

There for you must annoated modifying queries with `@Transactional`

Please find more information in the docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK , if you turn off auto-commit (which you [should](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43256/25720) especially for update , delete or insert) , you have to explicitly declare when to start and commit the transaction. Annotating `@Transactional` on a method allows you to do it declaratively (i.e. transaction starts before running that method and commit after the method return successfully)

I believe if the changes can still be applied to database without annotating with `@Transactional`, most probably auto-commit is turned on.

In other words , if auto-commit is turned off and a method is not annotated with `@Transactional` , the changes made inside a method will not take effect to the database since the transaction is not committed yet.